# Booting directly to Windows 10 without any option

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I'm a complete beginner to all of this and really need help as I've been trying for about a day now.

I use an Hp pavilion x360 if that's important (UEFI interface)

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKKdiqVHNqw&ab_channel=KskRoyal) tutorial on dualbooting and everything worked until the very end where my laptop booted directly to windows instead of giving me the option to choose.

[image: My partitions where I allocated 29gb for Ubuntu]

At first I thought, this was because I hadn't made partitions in my C: Drive like in the tutorial and so Ubuntu was on my secondary storage but googling this showed that wasn't the problem.

Then I tried changing the OS boot manager order through the BIOS but nothing changed.

I wasn't sure if this was the right tab but this was the only one with the boot order in it

[image]

I heard that disabling Secure Boot and quick startup was something that people tried out but I wanted to be absolutely sure before messing around with that.

Comment: This is a screenshot after I had already installed ubuntu. The 28.79gb of space was what I had left unallocated before.

Comment: Definitely you need to turn off the Windows Power option for fast startup. Secure boot should not be an issue unless you have certain hardware like Nvidia. Your disk0 does not have an EFI partition, so that prevents you booting it as a device, but grub should boot from the disk1 EfI.

Comment: You need **unpartitioned** free space to install Ubuntu.  Don't use Windows to prep your partitions for Ubuntu.  You can use the "Disks" utility (`gnome-disk-utility`) from the live session to delete partition(s) to make room for Ubuntu.  Watch what you're doing and don't delete the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the quick startup, and if you are using two discs (One for ubuntu and one for windows) try booting from the disc with ubuntu first, through this you will have the GRUB menu to choose which system you want to start, usually windows used to have the bcd menu but that was on 7

Comment: How do I boot from the Ubuntu disc? I don't know how to boot from one specific disc.

Comment: @SelfishStoic When you boot the machine it usually flashes for a second the key to access the boot options, it could be f7, f12, etc. It probably would show you the discs you can boot from. Ubuntu is on your "WDC...".

Comment: on the UEFI menu, in the option of boot manager, disable another option except the ubuntu disc, you always can try the "Boot selection menu" it differs from pc to pc but usually is the F11 (if not then search for the key, you must press it right after the manufacturer logo on start) (if you need more insight on the boot start information try this tutorial https://support.hp.com/za-en/document/c00364979)

Comment: I just checked the Boot options and there wasn't any WDC. The only other option was to boot through EFI file.

Comment: Judging by your screenshots, it looks like everything is ok, and you just need to disable fastboot in windows. Otherwise: the booting from EFI file option lets you browse the EFI filesystems. Look for grubx64.efi or shimx64.efi.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this worked for me:

- Disable "Legacy Support" at BIOS setup;
- boot up via the USB Ubuntu startup disk;
- run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

It should give you a screen from which OS to choose.

Answer (score 0):

Windows directly boots in Windows means that it's default boot manager is windows boot manager. I dual booted my laptop with Kali Linux and I don't know about ubuntu, but you should choose grub as your default boot manager.
To check please respond with this command (cmd) `bcdedit /enum FIRMWARE`